# What is the meaning of $\left.\frac{df_1}{dt}\right|_{coll.}$?

Tags: differentiation, kinetic-theory

In 'Statistical Physics of Particles' by Kardar and in these [pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-333-statistical-mechanics-i-statistical-mechanics-of-particles-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_333F13_Lec8.pdf) lecture notes (pg6) the quantity:

$$\left.\frac{df_1}{dt}\right|_{coll.}$$

is introduced in the context of BBGKY Hierarchy. As far as I can see there is not definition of what this actually means (i.e. what the $\left. \right|_{coll.}$ means). Please can someone explain? (a source would also be helpful)

Comment: Probably just the change in f_1 due to collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It says in the pdf that you attached :

> Kinematics of collision and scattering

So $|_{coll}$ means $\textbf{collision}$. Basically they study the change of $f_1$ in time, due to collisions.
 In this pdf, $f_1$ is the one-particle density. You can find its definition at the beginning of the document. Read it carefully before you ask something.